# My 3D racing game has some problems like wheels turning y axis and car not going anywhere

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My car's tires spin but the car doesn't move an inch and the wheels turn into y axis instead of left and right. Here is my code, i added rigidbody and boxcollider onto my car aswell maybe that's a problem causing the car not to move? (i made sure to put the collider above the wheels to make sure that they spin.)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CarController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float horizontalInput;
    private float verticalInput;
    private float steerAngle;
    private bool isBreaking;

    public WheelCollider FrontLeftCollider;
    public WheelCollider FrontRightCollider;
    public WheelCollider BackLeftCollider;
    public WheelCollider BackRightCollider;
    public Transform FrontLeftTransform;
    public Transform FrontRightTransform;
    public Transform BackLeftTransform;
    public Transform BackRightTransform;

    public float maxSteeringAngle = 30f;
    public float motorForce = 50f;
    public float brakeForce = 0f;


    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        GetInput();
        HandleMotor();
        HandleSteering();
        UpdateWheels();
    }

    private void GetInput()
    {
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        isBreaking = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space);
    }

    private void HandleSteering()
    {
        steerAngle = maxSteeringAngle * horizontalInput;
        FrontLeftCollider.steerAngle = steerAngle;
        FrontRightCollider.steerAngle = steerAngle;
    }

    private void HandleMotor()
    {
        FrontLeftCollider.motorTorque = verticalInput * motorForce;
        FrontRightCollider.motorTorque = verticalInput * motorForce;

        brakeForce = isBreaking ? 3000f : 0f;
        FrontLeftCollider.brakeTorque = brakeForce;
        FrontRightCollider.brakeTorque = brakeForce;
        BackLeftCollider.brakeTorque = brakeForce;
        BackRightCollider.brakeTorque = brakeForce;
    }

    private void UpdateWheels()
    {
        UpdateWheelPos(FrontLeftCollider, FrontLeftTransform);
        UpdateWheelPos(FrontRightCollider, FrontRightTransform);
        UpdateWheelPos(BackLeftCollider, BackLeftTransform);
        UpdateWheelPos(BackRightCollider, BackRightTransform);
    }

    private void UpdateWheelPos(WheelCollider wheelCollider, Transform trans)
    {
        Vector3 pos;
        Quaternion rot;
        wheelCollider.GetWorldPose(out pos, out rot);
        trans.rotation = rot;
        trans.position = pos;
    }

}
```

If needed i can send screenshots of things please don't be shy to ask.

I haven't tried anything too afraid to make it worse

Comment: I think you may have horizontal and vertical reversed.  Car movement is normally horizontal direction, not vertical.  Vertical is used if you are going up a hill and the angle will determine the horizontal and vertical speeds.

Answer (score 0):

A rigidbody will not move until some kind of force is applied to it, or you use it's MovePosition method. Here is a link ... https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html